# CLUSTER BY on String in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have following query in Hive

```
CREATE TABLE bucketed_users (id INT, name STRING,FlatNumber INT)
CLUSTERED BY (id) INTO 4 BUCKETS;
```

Is clustering only possible on only INT column(also on `FlatNumber`) or we can define custom function which will provide logic for dividing into buckets for clustering?

Answer (score 2):

Cluster/bucket can be created on any column, for non numeric column HIVE will use the **HASH(col)%"number of buckets"** to find the bucket for the record.

Comment: What HASH function will hive use for strings?